# Wrapper - Catching the methods of a subclass not reimplemented

Tags: python, oop, wrapper

I would like to wrap class of an existing huge package like for example `matplotlib` but my wrapper will not implement all the method. For example, in my MWE, I would to raise an exception to say that the class `Bidon2` has not implemented `method_2`.

My problem is that the module not necessarily implements a system of abstract class. Is there a way to fix that ?

### module.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Bidon():
    def method_1(self):
        print('Method 1')

    def method_2(self):
        print('Method 2')
```

### wrapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import module

class Bidon2(module.Bidon):
    def method_1(self):
        print('New Method 1')


Bidon2().method_1()

Bidon().method_2()
```

### Output

```
New Method 1
Method 2
```

Comment: Do you have a whitelist/blacklist of methods that you want to pass through/not pass through? Or just fail on anything not explicitly defined in `Bidon2`?

Comment: Yes I want a fail on anything not explicitly defined in `Bidon2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of ugly, but it works. Basically, you can use `dir` to get a full list of all attributes/methods supported by this class. Then, you can use the class `__dict__` to get what's actually defined in that class itself. Below, for any attr that's defined in the base class and not actually defined in the current class, we monkey-patch it to point at our own routine to raise an exception.

```
class Bidon2(Bidon):
    def method_1(self):
        print 'New method 1'
    def raise_attr_error(self):
        raise AttributeError, 'Attribute not supported!'
    def __init__(self):
        all_funcs = [x for x in dir(self) if not x.startswith('_')]
        all_funcs = [x for x in all_funcs if x not in Bidon2.__dict__]
        for x in all_funcs:
            setattr(self, x, self.raise_attr_error)
```

Comment: Thanks for this first big step but this approach needs to add extra codes to each class. I will look tomorrow for an adaptation using a base class for all the reimplemented classes that will do what you have proposed.

Comment: I think you are going to have to add some code somewhere, but if you can put it in a base class, that will limit what you have to do. You should be able to get the parent class from `self.__mro__` too, to avoid hard-coding it here.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. As soon as I find time to play with that, I produce another solution, and I add it to my initial question.